Reading barcode on Android
I'm working on a barcode reading library at my work, and today I received some examples to test this. However, these examples are of blank barcodes with a black background.
Everything works normally on iOS devices, but on Android, the barcodes are not read, only QRCodes with the same colors (white QRCodes with a black background) can be read normally.
Do I need to do something different for barcodes to work on Android?

You have the option of trying a normal read followed by a read on the negative image.

I never thought about that. I will try to change to read on the negative image.
